# How to stop `translate` transform from causing an element to be treated as position relative?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms

I have an absolutely positioned div which is a child of a statically-positioned parent container. I'm finding that applying `transform: translateY(-50%)` to the container is causing the child to treat this container as though it were `position: relative`.

When I check `absolutelyPositionedChild.offsetParent`, it points to the container. And when I get `container.computedStyleMap().get('position')`, it gives me `CSSKeywordValue {value: 'static'}`. So it is most certainly static, and yet it's being used as the reference. The second I disable the `transform` in the dev tools inspector, the `offsetParent` changes to a much higher div that contains the whole app - as intended.

Is this documented somewhere or am I misunderstanding something? More pertinently, is there a way to force it to not be treated as the offsetParent?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the `transform` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform),

> If the [transform] property has a value different than `none`, a stacking context will be created. In that case, the element will act as a containing block for any `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` elements that it contains.

And according to [the `containing block` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block),

> If the `position` property is `static`, `relative`, or `sticky`, the containing block is formed by the edge of the content box of the nearest ancestor element that is either a block container (such as an inline-block, block, or list-item element) or establishes a formatting context (such as a table container, flex container, grid container, or the block container itself).

So in this case, the parent element (a containing block that is statically-positioned) inherits the formatting context of the nearest block container. You will have an ancestor with `position: relative` that is cascading the formatting context.

To prevent this, you can make use of [`position: revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) (though note that it won't work in Internet Explorer).

Comment: The contaning block explains exactly why this is happening, however `position: revert` does not work for me.